# LINQ - If table doesn't contains any data left outer join query return a exception

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query which performs a left join with sub query in linq. But sub query doesn't have any value. In that case linq throws a exception. Here is my code

```
IEnumerable<MemberDetailsViewModel> query = await (from account in _context.Account
                                                           join kym in _context.KYMMaster on account.ClientId equals kym.Id
                                                           join address in _context.KYMAddress on kym.Id equals address.MasterId
                                                           join branch in _context.Branches on kym.BranchId equals branch.Branch_Id
                                                           join deposit in (
                                                                //this subquery doesnot have any value
                                                                from d in _context.Deposit
                                                                where d.AccountNo == accountNo
                                                                group d by d.AccountNo into grp
                                                                select new
                                                                {
                                                                    AccountNo = grp.Key,
                                                                    Balance = grp.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                                                                }
                                                           ) on account.AccountNo equals deposit.AccountNo into temp
                                                           from deposit in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                           where account.AccountNo == accountNo
                                                           select new MemberDetailsViewModel
                                                           {
                                                               ClientId = kym.ClientId,
                                                               ClientName = kym.ClientName,
                                                               Mobile = kym.MobileNo,
                                                               Address = AddressHelper.GetAddress(address),
                                                               Branch = branch.Branch_Name,
                                                               AvailableBalance = deposit == null ? 0.00M : deposit.Balance
                                                               //AvailableBalance = temp == null ? 0.00M : temp.
                                                           })
                       .AsNoTracking()
                       .ToListAsync();
```

As mentioned on code subquery doesn't have any value where i have perform a left join. How do i solve this??

Here is the actual exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
> at lambda_method108(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader ,
> ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1
> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at TechnoSys.Coop.Repository.DepositRepository.GetMemberDetailsByAccountAsync(String accountNo) in D:\Project\Inventory\netcoreapp\Repository\Implementation\TechnoSys.Coop.Repository\DepositRepository.cs:line 53    at TechnoSys.Coop.Service.DepositService.GetMemberDetailsByAccountAsync(String accountNo) in D:\Project\Inventory\netcoreapp\Service\Implementation\TechnoSys.Coop.Service\DepositService.cs:line 75    at TechnoSys.Coop.Controller.DepositController.GetAccountForDeposit(String accountNo) in D:\Project\Inventory\netcoreapp\Controller\TechnoSys.Coop.Controller\DepositController.cs:line 23    at lambda_method101(Closure , Object )    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate
> next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy,
> PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Comment: For a start, you could add the execption you are seeing to the question ...

Comment: Post the actual *full* exception text, not just the message. This isn't thrown because the table is empty. LINQ queries are translated to SQL which just doesn't care about NULLs. If there are no rows, there are no rows. The entire query though is a **very strong warning** that the design is simply wrong. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from relations. If you need to use 5 joins in a LINQ query, either your model is wrong or you shouldn't be using LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified query for LINQ translator and it should work.

```cs
var depositQuery = 
    from d in _context.Deposit
    where d.AccountNo == accountNo
    group d by d.AccountNo into grp
    select new
    {
        AccountNo = grp.Key,
        Balance = grp.Sum(x => x.Amount)
    };

var query = 
    from account in _context.Account
    join kym in _context.KYMMaster on account.ClientId equals kym.Id
    join address in _context.KYMAddress on kym.Id equals address.MasterId
    join branch in _context.Branches on kym.BranchId equals branch.Branch_Id
    join deposit in depositQuery on account.AccountNo equals deposit.AccountNo into temp
    from deposit in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where account.AccountNo == accountNo
    select new MemberDetailsViewModel
    {
        ClientId = kym.ClientId,
        ClientName = kym.ClientName,
        Mobile = kym.MobileNo,
        Address = AddressHelper.GetAddress(address),
        Branch = branch.Branch_Name,
        AvailableBalance = (decimal?) deposit.Balance ?? 0.00M
    };

var result = await query
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```